# Warning in python ( tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified )

Tags: python, pandas

System:
       Windows 7 64-bit, 
       Python 2.7, 
       PyCharm 4.03

Code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    a = pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan])
    i = a.describe()
    print i

Output: 

**tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified**
count    2.000000
mean     1.500000
std      0.707107
min      1.000000
25%      1.250000
50%      1.500000
75%      1.750000
max      2.000000
dtype: float64
```

The code is running but I can't find why I have that warning.
I have search it but I could not find something relevant or something that makes sense to me.
I am not a programmer, I am a scientist.
Could someone explain it to me?
Should I worry or ignore it and move on?
Thank you.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you restart your session?

Comment: No and I have counter it and other times. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Are you working on a ssh server?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly and I think I do what an ssh server is, I will say no. I am not connected in a server. I am working in my home computer. Thank you for your response.